# Are Kumbha Mela and Pushkara same?

Tags: terminology

I am confusing between **Pushkara** and **Kumbha Mela**.
From Wikipedia I understand **Pushkara** and **Kumbha Mela**.

> **Pushkara**: Each river is associated with a zodiac sign, and the river for each
>    year's festival is based on which zodiac sign the planet Jupiter
>    (Bṛhaspati) is in at that time.
>
> **Kumbha Mela**: is held at each of these four places every twelfth year.

Are they correlated?

Answer (score 1):

Namaste

both are same.  South Indians term it as Pushkaralu and North Indians term it Kumbha Mela.

This pushkaralu or kumbh mela is a gathering point for various saints and sages to assemble and exchange views.  The ordinary public can gain in terms of associating or gathering in the holy saints/sages presence.

Saints are able to see the astral light of each person called aura.  In that wide public gathering, the saint/sage sees a bright light and calls that soul to him and directs further spiritual counselling.

Sri Ramakrishna Paramhansa identified Swami Vivekananda from such gathering, though that time Swami Vivekananda was still unrefined soul named as Narendra, but due to the strong aura and light, Sri Ramakrishna Paramahansa identified him as a potential spiritual giant.